# What is the best practice to download executable binary file and include in setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py

Working on the setup.py and having hard dependency on downloading a zip file and extract from it the executable binary.

The goal:
downloading XXX.zip, and being able to run the xxx.exe as part of my project.

My questions are:

1. What is the best practice for downloading and storing it ?
2. Any way I can include it as part of the package -> I'll be able to:

```py
import xxx
popen.call(xxx.__path__[0]\xxx.exe)
```

Comment: Can you include the downloaded zip with the package you are distributing or does it have to be downloaded after the package is installed?

Comment: Actually the goal is to download the zip as part of the package installation